# send an invite through android application to facebook friends

Tags: android, facebook

How to send an invitation to facebook friends through my App on Android..

Comment: Please elaborate on your question

Comment: i want to send an invite through android application to facebook friends?

Comment: I assume you have to start looking at the Android-Facebook-SDK? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: click add comment under your question and post comments here not below. Thats for **answers** . click `edit` in your question and update it with details of what you tried and specific problems. Then people will be able to help you.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
public void inviteFriends(Activity activity, ArrayList<FriendInfo> friendsIds){
    // Safe programming
    if(friendsIds == null || friendsIds.size() == 0)        
        return;

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

    // Get the friend ids
    String friendsIdsInFormat = "";
    for(int i=0; i<friendsIds.size()-1; i++){
        friendsIdsInFormat = friendsIdsInFormat + friendsIds.get(i) + ", ";
    }
    friendsIdsInFormat = friendsIdsInFormat + friendsIds.get(friendsIds.size()-1).getId();

    parameters.putString("to", friendsIdsInFormat);
    parameters.putString( "message", "Use my app!");

    // Show dialog for invitation
    mFacebook.dialog(activity, "apprequests", parameters, new Facebook.DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

[Facebook dialog reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/)

Comment: Alesqui:How to get facebook  friends id?