# invite Facebook friends through android app

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook invite friends-i tried this [send an invite through android application to facebook friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210655/send-an-invite-through-android-application-to-facebook-friends) but am getting error on line column71:EntityRef:expecting ';'  in dialog.

Comment: please post your relevant code and the error logs..